# Addition Sparse Matrix in C#

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix

I wrote a program for addition sparse Matrix in C#.
Could you please check my program work correctly?

First element in this array is a row, the second is column and the third is value.

> Matrix 1:
>
> > 1 2 8
> >
> > 1 3 10
> >
> > 2 4 5
> >
> > 3 1 9
>
> Matrix 2:
>
> > 0 2 3
> >
> > 1  3 10
> >
> > 4 4 5
> >
> > 3 1 1
> >
> > 3 3 15
> >
> > 1 4 66
> >
> > 1 1 25

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharp
{

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            List<int[]> Addition = new List<int[]>();
            List<int[]> listArray1 = new List<int[]>();
            listArray1.Add(new int[] { 1,2,8});
            listArray1.Add(new int[] { 1, 3, 10 });
            listArray1.Add(new int[] { 2, 4, 5 });
            listArray1.Add(new int[] { 3, 1, 9 });

            List<int[]> listArray2 = new List<int[]>();
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 0, 2, 3 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 1, 3, 10 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 4, 4, 5 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 3, 1, 1 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 3, 3, 15 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 1, 4, 66 });
            listArray2.Add(new int[] { 1, 1, 25 });

            for (int i = 0; i < listArray1.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < listArray2.Count; j++)
                {
                        if (listArray1[i][0] == listArray2[j][0])
                        {
                         if (listArray1[i][1] == listArray2[j][1])
                         {
                            Addition.Add(new int[] { listArray1[i][0], listArray1[i][1], listArray1[i][2]+ listArray2[j][2] });
                            listArray1.RemoveAt(i);
                            listArray2.RemoveAt(j);
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Addition.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{Addition[i][j]}   ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            for (int i = 0; i <listArray1.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{listArray1[i][j]}   ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < listArray2.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{listArray2[i][j]}   ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Program out is:

> 1 3 20
>
> 3 1 10
>
> 1 2 8
>
> 2 4 5
>
> 0 2 3
>
> 4 4 5
>
> 3 3 15
>
> 1 4 66
>
> 1 1 25

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because so is no code review site.

Comment: I want just check for correctly

Comment: @Hadi you should post this question to [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), because StackOverflow is about helping people solve problems, not reviewing their solutions